# Writing a python program takes an int argument and adds 1+1/2+1/3+1/4....1/n

Tags: python-2.7

I need to write a function, count(n), that takes a positive integer, n, and returns the value
1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + ⋯ + 1/n.

Ex
: Count(4) should yield 1+ 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4

I'm not sure how to do this?  Any help would be great .

def count(n):

```
for c in range(1, n+1):
    print c + 1/c
```

I cannot get it to start at the number one and I cannot get it to print in array format.

My results of count(4) are
count(4)

2.0 (should be 1)

2.5 (should be 1.5)

3.33333333333 (should be 1.833333)

4.25(should be 2.083333)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this isn't a code writing service

Comment: I'm attempting to learn.  I've been at this for 2hours.  I figure if I see the code, i can work backwards as to how it works.

Comment: `count = lambda n : sum(1./iGotThisFromStackOverflow for iGotThisFromStackOverflow in range(1,n+1))`

Comment: `I've been at this for 2hours`. Show us what you've been working on, and we can help you fix it

Comment: @Tom that's irrelevant; please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking for guidance on what constitutes an acceptable question.

Comment: Apologies.  first timer.  I've added the code that I'm using.  Seems like this should be basic but I can't get it to function properly

Comment: Are you sure you're using python2.7? Either you are not posting the code that you are using, or you are using python3.x

Comment: I'm using 2.75. My code is written in text wrangler.  I'll cut and paste it again maybe its the formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are adding a preliminary `1` to `1/1` which gives `2`. Try this:

```
def count(n):
    sum = 0 #Intializing the return variable
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        sum+=1.0/i #Adding to the return variable
    return sum
```

This works as such:

```
>>> def count(n):
...     sum = 0
...     for i in range(1, n+1):
...             sum+=1.0/i
...     return sum
... 
>>> count(4)
2.083333333333333
>>> count(1)
1.0
>>> count(2)
1.5
>>> count(3)
1.8333333333333333
>>> count(4)
2.083333333333333
>>>
```

Comment: You only need a float on the top *or* the bottom of the division; `1 / float(i)` or `1.0 / i` (neater, IMO) are fine.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  Apologies if I was initially using the board wrong

Comment: @Tom, if this helped, please click on the green check next to my answer. It gives *you* reputation too!